# Convert character string to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert a character string in T-SQL to a date. I cannot change the format as this is hard coded in program where this information come from.
My character string format is dd/mm/yyyy Example 08/01/2002

When I use code:
`CONVERT(char(10), TRY_CAST([Birth Date] As Date), 103) As [DOB]`
it returns mm/dd/yyyy Example 01/08/2002

Of course when data is 31/01/2005 the code returns NULL .

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to convert it to a date then why are you even mentioning a format? A date stored correctly in a data datatype column doesn't have a display format, that only happens when you try and display it - which should happen in your front end, not SQL Server. Maybe you are confusing the default format SSMS uses to display dates with the way they are stored? In fact in your case the style format `108` is dictating how it is displayed, so change that to the correct style if you must format it in SQL Server.

Comment: Oh and `try-cast` doesn't allow you to specify the format you are passing in, but `try_convert` does. Try `TRY_CONVERT(date, '8/01/2002', 103)`.

Comment: If you want to convert *to* a date then you want `CONVERT(date,...`

Comment: `SELECT PARSE('08/01/2022' AS DATE USING 'AR-LB')` is cool to know about too if you're on SQL Server 2012 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select FORMAT(convert(date,  '31/01/2005', 103), 'dd/MM/yyyy') as dte
```

| dte |
| --- |
| 31/01/2005 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/689LQDar)

Comment: Hi Danny Thank you.  It kind of work, I can now use this field to calculate age or so, which I wasn't able to do before as it was character string. What would be the code to make it show as 31/01/2005? I know it seems weird that I want it to show same as it is, however I am not able to use the original field for calculations, would be great if I can have it display 31/01/2005 being a date.